# TYPO3: pass categories to mask content element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x, tx-mask

In a TYPO3 8.7 project I am using a DatabaseQueryProcessor to fetch the categories of a page and pass them as a parameter to fluid. Works.

But I want to have these categories in a mask content element as well. What is the best approach to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.

Problem was that I used the data processor on the page template level. Now I moved the data processor to a single typoscript object of type "FLUIDTEMPLATE" which is accessible inside a mask template as well.